# Decorrelate a query using semi join

Tags: database, multiset, semi-join

I am new to query optimization,how to use semi join while implementing decorrelation I can't totally understand.

Consider the query

```
        SELECT A, B
        FROM r
        WHERE r.B < SOME (
            SELECT B
            FROM s
            WHERE s.A = r.A
       )
```

Show how to decorrelate the above query using the multi-set version of
the semi-join operation

Answer (score 0):

You may write your query using an inner join as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.A, r.B
FROM r
INNER JOIN s
    ON r.A = s.A
WHERE r.B < s.B;
```

The `DISTINCT` clause is necessary in this version of your query, because a given record in the `r` table could potentially join to more than one match in the `s` table.  In your original version, there can't be duplicates, because of the `SOME` clause which take a set of records any always returns a single yes/no answer.